# Error after login: Cannot write bytes: broken pipe

Tags: 12.04, login

It all started when I was going to launch `GIMP` (GNU Image Manipulation Program). But it didn't, and suddenly nothing worked anymore. I could not even shut my laptop down from `unity`. So I forced it by holding down the ON/OFF button until the laptop was off. 
After re-starting the laptop and logging into into my account, Ubuntu froze at the white screen you sometimes see for a short moment (at least that is what I see usually) before you see your normal desktop. In this state it seems to be able to load my user account since software liky redshift is turns the screen redish. 
I then did nothing, just listening how the fan started spinned faster since the CPU were used more, when suddenly the initially white screen turned black screen with an error message:

```
Cannot write bytes: broken pipe.
```

I tried all the solutions I could find in the web:

I go to TTY1 using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>

1. re-installing Ubuntu desktop: `itsfoss.com/fix-unity-freezes-after-login-ubuntu-14-04`
2. re-installing graphics driver: [using link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)
   (here could be a problem, since even before I run into this problem today I the CPU needed to work hard to show e.g. vimeo movies)
3. reinstalled `xserver-xorg` by typing:

   sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
4. `mount -o remount,rw,errors=remount-ro /`
5. logging in with Unity `2d` gave me the same white screen and after long the same error message
6. I can log in with the Guest account but well, all my files not there. When I log out again from guest, I see the black screen with the error message `Cannot write bytes: broken pipe` for a sec. again before I get into the Log in window.
7. removing all .Xauthority files from home directory with:

   sudo rm .Xauthority*
8. typing `startx` gave me the message:

   xauth: file /home//.Xauthority does not exist
   Fatal server error:
   Server is already active for display 0

   ......(some more text).......

   Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxinit: giving up
   xinit: unable to connect to X server

But all of that lead to nothing so far. It didn't change anything. Only that now when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to get to TTY1 I see an error at the log in: `Plymouth command failed`. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> gives me the normal authorization login wihout out the Plymouth error for the shell (so that does not give me access to my account).

Technical Data:

Laptop: [here](https://www.sony.de/support/de/content/cnt-specs/VPCSE2S1E/list)

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot with Windows 7

not sure if this info gives any hints, but when check defunct programes with

```
ps -ef | grep defunct
```

I get:

```
00:01:49 gnome-settings- <defunct>
00:01:42 nm-applet <defunct>
00:01:44 nautlius <defunct>
00:01:50 notify-osd <defunct>
00:01:40 update-notifier <defunct>
00:00:00 grep --color=auto defunct
```

Important to add, as I just found out when checking my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
....(text)....
[821.609] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: UNSUPPRTED-13.35.1005
....(text)....
[823.270] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.org Foundation" compiled for 1.13.3, module version = 2.21.6 Module class: X.Org Video Driver
ABI class: X.Org video dDriver,version 13.1
[823.270] (II) fglrx(0): pEnt->device->identifier=0x7f...blablabla
[823.271] Fatal server error:
[823.271] atiddxProbe: fail to probe inel VGA device
```